# Change icon for a cx_Freeze script

Tags: python, python-3.x, icons, cx-freeze

I was just wondering if it's possible to change the program icon for a cx_Freeze script, I've looked around but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: The `icon` option is listed in the docs: http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe IIRC, you need to have a .ico file for it to work on Windows, so if it's in another format, you'll have to convert it manually.

Comment: Thomas You've been very helpful lately ;)

Answer (score 25):

Just add `icon="icon.ico"` in `Executable()` like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

target = Executable(
    script="your_program.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
    compress=False,
    copyDependentFiles=True,
    appendScriptToExe=True,
    appendScriptToLibrary=False,
    icon="icon.ico"
    )

setup(
    name="name",
    version="1.0",
    description="the description",
    author="the author",
    options={"build_exe": options},
    executables=[target]
    )
```